# FastCGI, PHP, Sendmail, and Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, fastcgi, sendmail

I am experiencing an odd issue.  I just switched to FastCGI (Apache) because of the big performance boost.  Everything is working great, except when I attempt to use sendmail (Codeigniter Class or just raw PHP).  I have tested with and without CI and still get a 500 internal server error when trying to send.  Could this be getting caused by a discrepency in how FastCGI utilizes sendmail?  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Also, the email will send, it just errors afterwards.  Please let me know a solution if you have one!  Thanks! :)

Comment: A 500 always leaves a log entry in Apache's error log. Check what it says there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out your php.ini file. it will be a different to the one that is being used by the webserver. In that you will find your PATH, and installed libraries, which will all be relevant to using Sendmail.